# Copy schema and data changes from one SQL Server DB to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, deployment

Can someone please advise me on the below.

I have 2 databases, both of then were identical until few years back when we started to add more tables, procedures, views triggers etc to one of the database. Now i have to copy all the changes made in database 1 to database 2.

Please, can someone throw some pointers or links which can guide me to accomplish the above

Massive thanks in advance

Cheers
Amit

Answer (score 6):

Check out Red Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) - and FYI there's also [Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) that will synchronise data too. There are trial versions you can try out.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [SQL Examiner Suite](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner_Suite/). I'm using this tool for a while and I love it.